# Jquery Pagination Record

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

wanna to ask how to show the correct entries row (yellow background part) based on the record in table? For example, if i choose "Show 5 rows" per page, the result will be "Showing 1-5 out of {total entries}", and when i click on second page, it will be "Showing 6-10 out of {total entries}". Hope someone can teach me.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  getPagination('#Tabla');
 });

 function getPagination(table) {

   $('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
  $('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination 
  var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter 
  var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option
  var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows 
  $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
    trnum++; // Start Counter 
    if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows

   $(this).hide(); // fade it out 
    }
    if (trnum <= maxRows) {
   $(this).show();
    } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
  }); //  was fade out to fade it in 
  if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
    var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..  
    // numbers of pages 
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li 
   $('.pagination').append('<li class"wp" data-page="' + i + '">\
            <span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
          </li>').show();
    } // end for i 
  } // end if row count > max rows
  $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li 
  $('.pagination li').on('click', function() { // on click each page
    var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
    var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
    $('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li 
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked 
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
   trIndex++; // tr index counter 
   // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
   if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
     $(this).hide();
   } else {
     $(this).show();
   } //else fade in 
    }); // end of for each tr in table
  }); // end of on click pagination list
   }).trigger('change');

   // end of on select change 
   // END OF PAGINATION 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
 <option value="1" selected>Show 1 Rows</option>
 <option value="3">Show 3 Rows</option>
 <option value="5">Show 5 Rows</option>
 <option value="5000">Show ALL Rows</option>
</select>

<table id="Tabla">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Remark</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div style="float:left">
 <strong>Showing <i style="background-color:yellow">11 to 17 </i>out of <?=$count2?> Entries </strong> 
</div>

<div>
 <nav>
   <ul class="pagination" style="cursor:pointer"></ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out..just have used some math i.e **manipulation of `total_rows` variable that holds total number of rows of a page**.

Check out the updated code below:

```js
var initial = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  getPagination('#Tabla');
});

function getPagination(table) {

  $('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
    $('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination 
    var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter 
    var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option


    var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows 
    //console.log("maxRows---", maxRows, totalRows);
    $('#pagin').html(initial + " - " + maxRows);
    $('#totalData').html(totalRows);

    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter 
      if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows

        $(this).hide(); // fade it out 
      }
      if (trnum <= maxRows) {
        $(this).show();
      } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
    }); //  was fade out to fade it in 
    if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
      var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..  
      // numbers of pages 
      for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li 
        $('.pagination').append('<li class"wp" data-page="' + i + '">\
            <span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
          </li>').show();
      } // end for i 
    } // end if row count > max rows
    $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li 
    $('.pagination li').on('click', function() { // on click each page
      var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
      var total_rows = maxRows * pageNum; //get total no. of rows WRT page
      $('#pagin').html(total_rows - maxRows + " - " + total_rows);
      var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
      $('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li 
      $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked 
      $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
        trIndex++; // tr index counter 
        // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
        if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        } //else fade in 
      }); // end of for each tr in table
    }); // end of on click pagination list
  }).trigger('change');

  // end of on select change 
  // END OF PAGINATION 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
  <option value="1" selected>Show 1 Rows</option>
  <option value="3">Show 3 Rows</option>
  <option value="5">Show 5 Rows</option>
  <option value="5000">Show ALL Rows</option>
</select>

<table id="Tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Remark</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abu</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ali</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div style="float:left">
  <strong>Showing <i id="pagin" style="background-color:yellow"></i> out of <span id="totalData"></span> Entries </strong>
</div>

<div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="pagination" style="cursor:pointer"></ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you explain what's the logic behind.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman sure!...updated my answer and code

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  getPagination('#Tabla');
 });

function getPagination(table) {


  $('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
  $('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination 
  var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter 
  var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option
    


var show=trnum+1+' to '+maxRows;
$('#show').html(show);

    
    var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows 
    
    console.log(totalRows);
    $('#totalrow').html(totalRows);
  
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter 
     if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows
          $(this).hide(); // fade it out 
     }
       
     if (trnum <= maxRows) {
        $(this).show();
     } 
       // else fade in Important in case if it ..
  }); //  was fade out to fade it in 
  if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
    var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..  
    // numbers of pages 
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li 
   $('.pagination').append('<li class"wp" data-page="' + i + '">\
            <span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
          </li>').show();
    } // end for i 
  } // end if row count > max rows
  $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li 
  $('.pagination li').on('click', function() { // on click each page
    var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
    var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter  
      
      var last=(pageNum * maxRows)
      var first= last-maxRows+1;
      if(last>maxRows){
        last= totalRows
      }
      var show=first+' to '+ last;
       $('#show').html(show);
       
    $('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li 
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked 
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
   trIndex++; // tr index counter 
   // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
   if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
     $(this).hide();
   } else {
     $(this).show();
   } //else fade in 
    }); // end of for each tr in table
  }); // end of on click pagination list
   }).trigger('change');

   // end of on select change 
   // END OF PAGINATION 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
 <option value="1" selected>Show 1 Rows</option>
 <option value="3">Show 3 Rows</option>
 <option value="5">Show 5 Rows</option>
 <option value="5000">Show ALL Rows</option>
</select>

<table id="Tabla">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Remark</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Abu</th>
   <th>Test2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ali</th>
   <th>Test1</th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div style="float:left">
 <strong>Showing <i style="background-color:yellow"><span id='show'></span> </i>out of <span id='totalrow'></span> Entries </strong> 
</div>

<div>
 <nav>
   <ul class="pagination" style="cursor:pointer"></ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```